# How can I figure out if a Safari extension is using unreasonable memory/cpu?

Tags: macos, safari, safari-extensions

How can I figure out if a Safari extension is using unreasonable memory/cpu? I'm not really experiencing any unreasonable sluggishness, but I am starting to pile up on the extensions and was considering pruning the most performance draining ones just for good measure.

Answer (score 2):

Disable the extension.  Run Safari for an hour (normal use) and note the kind of cpu/memory usages you get from it (using activity monitor or top).

Enable the extension.  Repeat.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Instruments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruments_%28application%29) and attach it to your safari instance and start from there.

Comment: How do I attach it to my safari instance? Does it still work nowadays when extensions are external processes?

Comment: Sorry @gio91ber I have stopped using macOS around 2016 so I have no idea if you can still do this.